How does one import Natural numbers in Lean 4 -- unknown identifier 'ℕ'?
I found the definition of Nat's but lean still complains that it doesn't exist. Why is it?
import Init.Data.Nat.Basic
import Init.Prelude

-- theorem addition, 0 + n = n (not inductive proof)
theorem zero_add_n : ∀ n : ℕ, 0 + n = n := by rfl

Error
unknown identifier 'ℕ'


Note my definition using reals does work:
import Mathlib.Data.Real.Basic

-- Define the limit of a function at a point
def limit (f : ℝ → ℝ) (x' : ℝ) (l : ℝ) : Prop :=
```


They're there, they're just called Nat. If you want the abbreviation ℕ to work then you'll need a mathlib import e.g. import Mathlib.Data.Real.Basic will be fine. You can then right-click on the notation and try and figure out in exactly which file the definition of the notation is made.
In your example you're just importing Init stuff, which is in core and not mathlib.

hmmm that is confusing. Because I went to the code that Init.Prelude and it was the definition of Nat. But I guess the appreviation isn't here?

Yes, @CharlieParker, as Kevin said the natural numbers are in core Lean (the prelude file as you said) as Nat, but the unicode abbreviation ℕ is defined in Mathlib here: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/Init/Data/Nat/Notation.html
